# set marker in map using angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angular-ui-router

I am working on am application. There are two pages. In the first page, i am showing the country and there lat & lng. When I click on any country it redirect to 2nd page. In this page I am showing google map. according to map a marker is showing. That's work perfectly.

Problem is that in 2nd page I use two textbox, from this textbox I enter lat & lng and when hit button marker should change there place. it's not working. I am not understanding where i am doing wrong. If i missing any thing please help me.

CODE

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    myApp.controller('mapCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $stateParams) {
        $scope.lat = $stateParams._lat;
        $scope.lng = $stateParams._lng;


        $scope.clickMe = function (clicked) {
            $scope.lat = $scope.txtLatitude;
            $scope.lng = $scope.txtLongitude;
        };
    })
      .factory('mapsInit', mapsInitFactory)
      .directive('myMap', myMap);

    function mapsInitFactory($window, $q) {
        //Google's url for async maps initialization accepting callback function
        var asyncUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDpqr0uW01dCVmuSCxo7XizH47-ZUuyEZM&callback=',
            mapsDefer = $q.defer();

        //Callback function - resolving promise after maps successfully loaded
        $window.googleMapsInitialized = mapsDefer.resolve; // removed ()

        //Async loader
        var asyncLoad = function (asyncUrl, callbackName) {
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            //script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = asyncUrl + callbackName;
            document.body.appendChild(script);
        };

        //Start loading google maps
        asyncLoad(asyncUrl, 'googleMapsInitialized');

        //Usage: Initializer.mapsInitialized.then(callback)
        return {
            mapsInitialized: mapsDefer.promise
        };
    }

    function myMap(mapsInit) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                mapId: '@id', // map ID
                lat: '@',     // latitude
                long: '@'     // longitude
            },
            link: function (scope) {
                console.log(scope.mapId, scope.lat, scope.long);
                if (angular.isDefined(scope.lat) && angular.isDefined(scope.long)) {

                    // Initialize the map
                    var initialize = function () {
                        var location = new google.maps.LatLng(scope.lat, scope.long);

                        var mapOptions = {
                            zoom: 6,
                            center: location
                        };

                        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(scope.mapId), mapOptions);

                        new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: location,
                            map: map
                        });
                    };
                    mapsInit.mapsInitialized.then(function () {
                        initialize();
                    }, function () {
                    });
                }
            }
        };

    }

})();
```

Comment: It looks like you expect google API to use two-way data binding, this isn't working that way, when the value has changed you have to programmatically move the marker

Comment: so how i will achieve? i tired everything that i know.

Answer (score 0):

First, you will need a reference to the marker in question:

```
scope.mainMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: location,
                        map: map
                    });
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.clickMe = function (clicked) {
        $scope.lat = parseFloat( $scope.txtLatitude );
        $scope.lng = parseFloat( txtLongitude );

        $scope.mainMarker.setLocation(new google.maps.LatLng(
                                 $scope.lat,
                                 $scope.lng
                                 ));

    };
```